# Pressure and volume

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, volume

Currently, I am working on this experiment where I hit a balloon with a small object so that the pressure inside a balloon changes.

The pressure increased when I hit the balloon, but I need to explain why it increased. When hitting an object from outside, I can use the equation

pressure = force/area

and if pressure from the outside on the surface of the balloon increases, intuitively, it is clear that the volume inside the balloon decreases, thus, increasing the pressure inside the balloon (if i assume that it's ideal gas.).

so I want to ask if there are any equations that involve the pressure from the outside, and the volume or pressure inside an object such as a balloon.

Comment: I think you already have your explanation? You decrease the volume, so the pressure increases. I am not sure what more you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you hit the balloon with a small object, you are applying an impulse.  Both the force and area will vary (over a very short period of time).  The impulse will propagate through the air in the balloon (like a shock wave), and through the membrane of the balloon.  You are dealing with transient effects which do not lend themselves to a simple mathematical description.

Comment: Also the material of the balloon is difficult to analyze because of transients. The tension of the gummi sheet has a strong hysteresis (that is why it is difficult at the beginning to inflate new balloon).

Answer (score 0):

You may simply state that since the balloon is in equilibrium, the pressure inside is equal to the pressure outside (assuming that there is no air leaking through the material). Hence if you apply extra pressure outside, it is replicated inside too.

Comment: The atmospheric pressure outside of a balloon is much lower than the fluid pressure inside. The difference in force is provided by the elastic nature of the balloon membrane.

Comment: @BillN But the difference in pressure is much small than atmospheric pressure. (And not strongly dependent on the size of the balloon.)

Comment: But it is definitely greater or it wouldn't be inflated. And in the case of athletic balls, the gauge pressure is on the order of an atmosphere, so internal is 2X external, not at all equal. Small pressure differences are critical.